# JQuery: Modify all elements except the one I'm clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the opacity of all other elements called `emotion-choice` that I'm not clicking, but `.not()` is new for me, so I'm not very familiar with this and could need some help. This is my code:

```
$('#modal-content').on('click', '.emotion-choice', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);        
    var current = $('.emotion-choice > span > strong').text();
    $('.emotion-choice > span > strong').not(current).html('a');    
    console.log(this);
});
```

It would work if it's the same element that I'm clicking, but because it's a child element, this confuses me.

HTML (this is actually a loop and I want to change the title also):

```
<a class="emotion-choice" href="#">
            <span class="pull-left">
            <strong class="pl10">'.$emotions[$key].'</strong>
            </span>
            </a>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
$('#modal-content').on('click', '.emotion-choice', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).find('> span > strong').css('opacity',1);
    $(this).find('> span > strong > span').html('test');
    $('.emotion-choice').not(this).find('> span > strong').css('opacity',0.4);  
    $('.emotion-choice').not(this).find('> span > strong > span').css('opacity',0.4);
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="emotion-choice" href="#">
            <span class="pull-left">
            <strong class="pl10">'.$emotions[$key].'</strong>
            <span style="background:url(img/emotions.png) 0 -'.$y.'px; height:70px; width:90px; 
            display:block; margin:20px 15px 0 0"></span>
            </span>
            </a>
```

Comment: try with var current = $(this);

Comment: `.not()` accepts either an element or a selector (or a function).

Comment: @AramilRey: Or just `.not(this)`.

Comment: Yehp, just to keep the syntax, both should work :D

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your HTML, also, so that we can reproduce your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the clicked element from a set of elements. However, you are attempting to exclude an `<a>` element (the clicked element) from a selected set of `<strong>` elements. The element to which you've bound the click event is `<a>`, not `<strong>`.

Exclude the clicked element from the total set of `.emotion-choice` elements, and then select the `<strong>` tags *within* that set of elements (the set that excludes the clicked element).

```js
$('#modal-content').on('click', '.emotion-choice', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.emotion-choice').not(this).find('> span > strong').html('-');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal-content">
  <a class="emotion-choice"><span><strong>test1</strong></span></a>
  <a class="emotion-choice"><span><strong>test2</strong></span></a>
  <a class="emotion-choice"><span><strong>test3</strong></span></a>
  <a class="emotion-choice"><span><strong>test4</strong></span></a>
  <a class="emotion-choice"><span><strong>test5</strong></span></a>
  <a class="emotion-choice"><span><strong>test6</strong></span></a>
  <a class="emotion-choice"><span><strong>test7</strong></span></a>
</div>
```

Another way of visualizing this:

```
$('#modal-content').on('click', '.emotion-choice', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // define all "emotion" elements, excluding the clicked one (this)
  var $elements_excluding_this=$('.emotion-choice').not(this);  

  // select all "> span > strong" elements within the set of selected "emotion" elements
  var $strong_tags = $('> span > strong', $elements_excluding_this);

  // set the HTML content for the selected set of "strong" tags
  $strong_tags.html('-');

});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm also trying to change the opacity of an image right after the title (<strong> tag). I edited my question to show you what I mean. Could you help me with this also?

Comment: By the way: I also added `$(this).find('> span > strong').css('opacity',1);` to make an other element shown as "active" again when the user decides to click another element.

Comment: You want the clicked element to be `opacity:1` and the others to be `opacity:0.4`? Or just the images?

Comment: You're right. This is actually not smart. I guess I just need the whole `element-choice` to change its opacity. I just also wanted to add the class `grey` so the title-links aren't colorful. That's why I asked how to specificly change the title also. But I also could just add the class `grey` to the main element `element-choice` also.

Comment: Still, I learned something new and I'm thankful for your answer! I got my solution.